# Block based KVO: Block-KVO vs THObserversAndBinders vs KVOController

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-observing

[Block-KVO](https://github.com/iMartinKiss/Block-KVO) vs [THObserversAndBinders](https://github.com/th-in-gs/THObserversAndBinders) vs [KVOController](https://github.com/facebook/KVOController).

What are the pros and cons of each? Which one is better and why?

*UPDATE*: In the end, I'm leaning towards using [Objective-Chain](https://github.com/iMartinKiss/Objective-Chain) for processing KVO. [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa) is an option too, but maybe too overboard for this.

Comment: Why are you interested in "block based kvo" in the first place? What is wrong with KVO that it needs blocks?

Comment: KVO syntax is fugly, man.

Comment: The source code is all there, I've used the latter two, ultimately they weren't that different, but there really isn't a lot of code in either, I'd just take a look and see which one you like more.

Comment: Not sure why you say that. When done right it's pretty straightforward and simple. Using blocks for KVO introduces some interesting problems. You're almost guaranteed to have retain cycles (for good reason). Just like blocks aren't a good match for NSNotifications, they're not good for KVO.

Comment: I beg to disagree: in my opinion NSNotifications and KVO are the *perfect* use case for blocks. Blocks were not available when Apple implemented these features and they did not bother adding block support later. KVO syntax is not pretty to look at. `NSKeyValueObservingOptions` and the `change NSDictionary` give me the goosebumps (powerful as they might be). All these should be optional. There should be a simpler flavour of KVO were I don't need to worry about this stuff: give me the old value and the new one, I don't care about anything else.

Comment: Too bad the question was closed. A quick investigation shows the following. Block-KVO has a reacher interface (it provides the values explicitly) and supports one- and two-way mapping; THObserversAndBinders supports binding; KVOController doesn't. On the other hand KVOController and THObserver automatically remove observations upon dealloc, but I couldn't find a similar feature in Block-KVO (you have to remove observers manually). JFYI there's also simple [KeyValueObserver](https://github.com/objcio/issue-7-lab-color-space-explorer/blob/master/Lab%20Color%20Space%20Explorer/KeyValueObserver.m)

Comment: Drives me nuts when SO closes good discussions like this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, let me just say that this is a prime example of a subjective question that probably should not be asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)—you're clearly a well established member here and I'm sure you knew that already.

But since you asked, I'll try to answer your subjective question as unsubjectively as possible—while it's not the best question for Stack Overflow, it is a good question overall, and I'm sure a few Googlers will end up here looking for an answer, subjective or not!

---

First of all, if your only/main complaint about `KVO` is the syntax (as you mentioned in a comment on your question), *don't* go for [Objective-Chain](https://github.com/iMartinKiss/Objective-Chain) or its inspiration, [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa). While they have an incredible amount of [usefulness](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa#when-to-use-reactivecocoa), neither is worth their weight or complexity just for a more accessible `KVO` syntax.

Of the three libraries you mentioned to begin with, the one that pops out the most is [KVOController](https://github.com/facebook/KVOController)—between the straightforward syntax and being upfront about thread safety, you can let the large number of GitHub stars speak for themselves. **This is my recommendation** of the three options originally posted.

The other options, which also seem lightweight and feature great syntax, do have their own merits as well—[Block-KVO](https://github.com/iMartinKiss/Block-KVO) is the only option of the three to sport the MIT license instead of BSD, so if that's a preference of necesity for your project, keep that in mind—and [THObserversAndBinders](https://github.com/th-in-gs/THObserversAndBinders), despite not being updated since late 2013, features great documentation and a lack of Facebook ownership, if that's your thing too.

---

Hopefully that should give you an objective list to help you choose your best option—and be sure to keep it less open next time :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm against SO's policy of not being able to ask questions about comparing X with Y; this is because in the past I have found SO's comparison answers that have been super useful (and in many cases it was the only source for comparing X and Y). So I'm subverting the system within, and trying to get the policy changed. :D I did a good deal of Googling on block-based KVO and I couldn't found any decent comparison (and don't have the time to go over the code of the three projects myself). Anyway, no worries, I don't think I'll have to ask open ended questions any time soon.

Comment: But anyway I'm leaning towards Objective-Chain, as I mentioned. I want to try using some of its additional features (like block-based notifications and connecting two properties of different objects with a transformation between them).

Answer (score 4):

Here's a minimal working idea (I am also put off by the KVO style).  The idea is to carry the block in the KVO context, then invoke it when the observation is triggered.

```
//  NSObject+KVOBlock.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSObject (KVOBlock)

// invoke the block when the receiver's value at keyPath changes
// block params are the receiver, the keyPath and the old value
- (void)observeKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath withBlock:(void (^)(id, NSString *, id))block;
- (void)unobserveKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath;

@end

//  NSObject+KVOBlock.m

#import "NSObject+KVOBlock.h"

@implementation NSObject (KVOBlock)

- (void)observeKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath withBlock:(void (^)(id, NSString *, id))block {   
    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:keyPath
              options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld
              context:(__bridge void *)(block)];
}

- (void)unobserveKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath {

    [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:keyPath];
}

- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString*)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary*)change context:(void*)context {

    void (^block)(id, NSString *, id) = (__bridge void (^)(id, NSString *, id))context;
    block(self, keyPath, [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeOldKey]);
}

@end
```

Call it like this...

```
// assume a class called SomeObject with an instance called someObject
someObject.someProperty = @"Bar";

[someObject observeKeyPath:@"someProperty" withBlock:^(SomeObject *object, NSString *keyPath, NSString *oldValue) {

    // avoid referring directly to 'someObject' in this block, since it retains
    // the block via the kvo context, thereby causing a retain cycle.  The first
    // param ('object') is exactly equal to someObject. So use that instead.

    NSLog(@"object=%@, keyPath=%@, oldValue=%@, newValue=%@",
        object, keyPath, oldValue, object.someProperty);
}];

// at any point after this, when you change someProperty, the block will be invoked 
self.object.someProperty = @"Foo";
```

I did a mini test with the code above and confirmed that it worked at least in the case shown here.  The console output looked like this...

```
<SomeObject :0xblahblah>, keyPath=someProperty, oldValue=Bar, newValue=Foo
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's a nice use of the context argument. It's a shame I can not split the reputation bounty, I'd have liked to give you some of it. :-(

Comment: I hope nobody ever tries to use this code. Overriding common functions in a category like this is bound to create issues. What if some future implementation of NSObject also internally uses KVO? boom.